# weird problem about rake db:migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

all:

I got a weird Ruby problem.

[image]

please ignore those warning messages.  I just ran "rake db:migrate" command, it did do the migration for me, but it also remove some CSS files!!! it won't appear again while I run this command again.

Is that normal or just a fantastic bug?

my environments:

- OS: ubuntu
- ruby 1.8.7
- rails 3.0.7 with compass gem
- compass 0.11.4

and this is the content of my `config/compass.rb` file:

```
require "fancy-buttons"

project_type = :rails
project_path = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.root
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
environment = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.env
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
output_style = :compressed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a `compass clean` call somewhere in your initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I checked the `config` directory and I'm pretty sure I have no initializers call any command like `compass clean` . I tried several combinations, but I still can not reproduce the same situation. :)

Comment: Which version of compass are you using?  Also add the contents of your `config/compass.config` file to your question.

Comment: I use compass 0.11.4, and I added the `config/compass.rb` in the content above, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, brain fade - I meant your `config/initializers/compass.rb` file.

Comment: Oops! I don't have this initializer rb file in the `config/initializers` directory.

Comment: Just the defaults then, sorry - nothing there that I can think could cause your problems.

Comment: @高見龍 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1495/discussion-between-jason-king-and-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jason. I asked some of my friends and they also don't figure it out what's going on. (actuarially I also don't know how to reproduce the same situation again). I'll try harder by myself, maybe dig into the rake or compass source code to see if any chance to trigger the `compass clean` command. thank you again :)